# Wordpress 1-click install cons?

Tags: php, wordpress, customization, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm getting a webpage soon, and will probably be choosing WordPress, with bbPress for forums. 
Since the hosting company I'm considering has a 1-click installer for Wordpress I'm considering using that, but I'm wondering if I risk painting myself into a corner vs downloading and installing myself?

I want to add some custom PHP code, and customize the theme I choose quite a bit to suit my needs.

Comment: come on... installing wordpress by hand is a 2-click effort. try it once, it's really not that difficult

Answer (score 0):

Using your host to install WordPress won't be any different to you installing it yourself. It's easier if anything. You will still be able to add your own code to themes etc.

Every version of WordPress I have ever installed has been through my control panel and I've never had any issues.  It's just there to save a little time :)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience using 1-click with clients such as digital ocean or linode or many more. The one click install works perfectly. You just have to get some documentation as how the server is installed in terms as where is the root folder for your site located, how is the root user and permissions, which php packages does that 1-click have, so on.

It will be easier to start with one click, but as you get more experience, in my case, was much better to install everything myself. There are some very good examples on how to create your "skeleton" with everything you need to run Wordpress. When you need to add something else, you know it won't break your server, because you know what it has. If it's a 1 click install and you don't study the server, you might break things without knowing.

Resuming: Start with a 1-click and then move to your own specs on your server as you get more experience and confidence handling a LAMP or LEMP server.

Hope this helps you !!!